# cap() on channel is not constant?

Tags: go

```
ch := make(chan int, 10)
fmt.Println(cap(ch))
```

is function call `cap(ch)` *constant* or *evaluated*?

golang spec said:

> The expression len(s) is constant if s is a string constant. The expressions len(s) and cap(s) are constants if the type of s is an array or pointer to an array and the expression s does not contain channel receives or (non-constant) function calls; in this case s is not evaluated. Otherwise, invocations of len and cap are not constant and s is evaluated.

seems that is *evaluated*.

Comment: It is evaluated in the general case, although in this particular example I would not be surprised if the compiler optimized it into a constant.

Comment: @Evan OP asked about whether a call to `cap()` on a channel is a constant expression as there are certain places where only constant expressions are allowed. Even if the compiler could optimize the call to `cap()` into a constant, that wouldn't make the call a constant expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `cap()` is not constant when applied to a channel, as the capacity of a channel isn't encoded in the type and thus not known at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Sure  call cap(ch) evaluated, just because of

```
ch := make(chan int, 10)
fmt.Println(cap(ch))
ch = make(chan int, 9)
fmt.Println(cap(ch))
```

Proof-link https://play.golang.org/p/R0TfCpC-4L